# Update an external variable from inside a decorator

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2016

I have a bigger decorator, but just made a toy example of where my issue is.

I'm trying to update the result from inside a decorator, but it's giving me undefined. How can I do this?

```
let decorator = async (dummy, method) => {
    console.log(dummy)
    await method()
}
let dummy = 'dummy'
let result
decorator(dummy, async ()=> {
    result = await queryDatabase(queryParams)
})
console.log(result) // prints undefined
```

**UPDATE**

I realised I should just await the decorator. Now it's working.

Comment: How you know `queryDatabase` does not return `undefined`? `queryParams` is undefined

Comment: It is defined, but omitted here. I just realised the error: I should await the decorator! ...so stupid :-)

Comment: Ahaha you are right. It's async, `await decorator(....`

Comment: Ideally the `decorator` function should `return method()` instead of only `await`ing it. You then wouldn't have the hassle of dealing with closure variables, you could just return the `queryDatabase` result.

Comment: @Bergi the thing is that my `dummy` will be a function which is checking on the result. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @JoãoOtero Maybe you should ask a new question with your whole actual code about that. I cannot really judge from your toy example